# Jstree - Stop node from being move outside it's parent

Tags: jstree, jstree-dnd

I have a requirement where I need to restrict my jstree node not to move outside its parent. It can freely move inside within its parent.

This is the code I am trying:

```
$('#divUC').jstree({
    'core': {
        multiple: false,
        'check_callback': function (o, n, p, i, m) {
           if (o == "move_node" && n.type == "view") {
           }
```

Here shortcuts indicates:

- o = operation,
- n = node,
- p = node_parent,
- i = node_position,
- m = more

Comment: Got the answer  ->>  if (this.get_node(n).parent === this.get_node(p).id) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }

Comment: You can post you answer and mark it as approved

Answer (score 0):

You can check in [callback](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=chec&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback) for this.

```
if(operation =='move_node'){
 if (this.get_node(node).parent === this.get_node(node_parent).id) { 
     return true; 
  } else { 
     return false;
  }
 }
```